# Error in Payment methods: The following error(s) occurred: Some PayPal solutions conflict. Please re-enable the previously enabled payment solutions

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal

I am getting this error in payment methods in **Magento2.1.7** backend

> The following error(s) occurred: Some PayPal solutions conflict.
>   Please re-enable the previously enabled payment solutions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I have found the solution. In my case, I have enabled 2 payment method,
I have disabled it.
I have integrated Payments Pro payment method for my magento2 site.
I have referred this link https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/payment/paypal-payments-pro.html.
This link is the best for the integration of Payments Pro payment method.

Comment: Great! Thank Bro.